# How use variable declare inside function but print in another class function in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, variables, attributes

How can I print userInputVariable from aFunction of class A into class B in bFunction in Python?

````
    @staticmethod
    def aFunction():
        userInputVariable = input("Enter string: ")
        print("This print function not should use in bFunction but print in aFunction while i call aFunction")
        
class B(A):
    def bFunction():
        #Here print userInputVariable
        pass

b = B()
b.aFunction()
#Now bFunction should run and print userInputVariable```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def aFunction():
        userInputVariable = input("Enter string: ")
        print(userInputVariable)

class B(A):
    def bFunction(self):
        super().aFunction()


b = B()
b.bFunction()
```

> super() method to invoke parent class methods and variables

Comment: Sorry i left something to add in question So, please give answer again after seeing question. I want use print() function while i call aFunction but not use print () function while call bFunction

Comment: Do you need to use the aFunction's variable inside bFunction?

Comment: Yes how can i do please help me

Comment: I have updated the answer, if this doesn't solve your problem, please explain the question clearly. @RaviCoder